# installing entity framework with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework-5

I am having difficulty installing Entity Framework 5.0.0 (the latest non-beta version) for the first time.  Everything I've seen so far about how to install it mentions using the Package Manager feature of Visual Studio, which does not exist in Visual Studio 2008.  All I want is to download the dll, stick it in my bin folder, and add it as a reference!

I've managed to download the NuGet package (.nupkg file) through my browser, and nuget.exe.  I have run "nuget install entityframework", but I can't figure out where it installed it to.

All I need is the location of the EntityFramework dll file.  Does anyone know what the default install location is, or the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 4.0 and newer are available **only** for .NET 4.0 and newer.

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support .NET 4.0 - sorry, you won't be able to use EF 4.0/5.0 in a VS 2008 solution.

And the *Package Manager* feature (also known as `NuGet`) is only available in VS 2010 and newer, too. There's a command-line version of `NuGet` if that's on option for you - but the integrated *Package Manager* is not available in VS 2008 unfortunately.